# Using this script in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have this script and want to use it in a stored procedure but while creating it, it showed me an error:

> Error:
>        Query : CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`loadXMLData`()     BEGIN  LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE
>   UserApplication.xml'         INTO TABLE userapplicatio...
>        Error Code : 1314 LOAD XML is not allowed in stored procedures

Query:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'UserApplication.xml'
INTO TABLE userapplication
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Group>';
```

How can I achieve this task? Is there a alternative available for this?

Comment: script is most likely from pre 5.0.xyz era... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14977

Comment: You could use the idea from answer given to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967883/using-load-data-infile-command-in-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible run a `LOAD DATA` command from stored procedures, but you can run `LOAD DATA` directly without stored procedure in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

you can workaround the problem by creating a cronjob on server:

mysql -u[user] -p[passw] --execute="LOAD DATA INFILE …………”